# How do I set my Android Application class in my gradle file?

Tags: android, gradle

What is the equivalent of the config below in a Gradle file? I cannot for the life of me find it.

```
<application
    android:name="com.foobar.app.BaseCodeApplication"
>
```

Comment: You mean to say as in AndroidMenifest.xml? I do not think you need to specify application class in gradle file.

Comment: Ya, I thought the AndroidMenifest.xml was completely generated. And so lost an hour or 3 trying to track down how to do it in the gradle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent in the android gradle plugin.  These are the [manifest entries](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Manifest-entries) you can configure from gradle.  The application name is not one of them, so it goes in your manifest.